# Aggregating Every Combination of Variables in R Data Frame

Tags: r, aggregation

I have several variables in an R data frame, and I want to use group_by and summarise to count the number of times each combination of levels appears across variables.

For example, if I had 3 variables, I want to obtain counts for the levels in variable 1, then for variable 2, and again for variable 3. Then, I want to get counts for the combinations of levels in variables 1 & 2, 2 & 3, and 1 & 3. Finally, I want to get counts for the combinations of levels in variables 1, 2, & 3. I'm essentially doing multiple levels of aggregation across multiple variables.

My problem is that I don't know how to aggregate every combination of variables without performing a separate group_by/summarise for each combination and then binding them together. I imagine this is possible via a loop, but I don't know how to set it up. I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do this than a loop.

I have looked around and haven't been able to find how this could be done in R using group_by/summarise. I do know, however, that SAS PROC MEANS and PROC SUMMARY offer the NWAY functionality, which is what I think I'm looking for. Click link below for an image.

[image]

Here is a sample dataset and the repetitive process that I would need to use to get every combination of every variable.
`

```
test_data <- tribble(
  ~p, ~city, ~raceeth, ~age_grp,
  #---|----|----|-----
  "p1", "dc", "white", "18-29",
  "p2", "ny", "black", "30-49",
  "p3", "chi", "hisp", "18-29",
  "p4", "ny", "oth", "30-49",
  "p5", "ny", "white", "0-17",
  "p6", "dc", "hisp", "50-64",
  "p7", "ny", "oth", "0-17",
  "p8", "ny", "asian", "30-49",
  "p9", "chi", "oth", "50-64",
  "p10","chi", "black", "18-29"
)

test_data_tbl <- test_data %>% 
  summarise(total = n()) %>% 
  mutate(city = "All",
         raceeth = "All",
         age_grp = "All") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(level = 0) %>% 
  select(city,raceeth, age_grp, total, level)

test_data_tbl_c <- test_data %>% 
  group_by(city) %>%
  summarise(total = n()) %>% 
  mutate(raceeth = "All",
         age_grp = "All") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(level = 1) %>% 
  select(city,raceeth, age_grp, total, level)

test_data_tbl_r <-  test_data %>%  
  group_by(raceeth) %>% 
  summarise(total = n()) %>% 
  mutate(city = "All",
         age_grp = "All") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(level = 1) %>% 
  select(city,raceeth, age_grp, total, level) 

test_data_tbl_a <-  test_data %>%  
  group_by(age_grp) %>% 
  summarise(total = n()) %>% 
  mutate(city = "All",
         raceeth = "All") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(level = 1) %>% 
  select(city,raceeth, age_grp, total, level)

test_data_tbl_cr <-  test_data %>%  
  group_by(city,raceeth) %>% 
  summarise(total = n()) %>% 
  mutate(age_grp = "All") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(level = 2) %>% 
  select(city,raceeth, age_grp, total, level)

test_data_tbl_ca <-  test_data %>%  
  group_by(city,age_grp) %>% 
  summarise(total = n()) %>% 
  mutate(raceeth = "All") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(level = 2) %>% 
  select(city,raceeth, age_grp, total, level)

test_data_tbl_ra <-  test_data %>%  
  group_by(raceeth,age_grp) %>% 
  summarise(total = n()) %>% 
  mutate(city = "All") %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(level = 2) %>% 
  select(city,raceeth, age_grp, total, level)

test_data_tbl_cra <-  test_data %>%  
  group_by(city,raceeth,age_grp) %>% 
  summarise(total = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(level = 3) %>% 
  select(city,raceeth, age_grp, total, level)

test_data_final <- rbind(  test_data_tbl,
                           test_data_tbl_c,
                         test_data_tbl_r,
                         test_data_tbl_a,
                         test_data_tbl_cr,
                         test_data_tbl_ca,
                         test_data_tbl_ra,
                         test_data_tbl_cra)
```

Here is what is produced by the code above, and this is what I would like to get via a less repetitive solution.
[image]

Again, this is probably best achieved via a loop, but I'm open to any ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, we remove the p column, because it seems you don't actually want it in the output:

```
test_data |> select(-p) -> test_data
```

Next, load the tidyverse package, and generate all possible combinations of 0:n columns, where n is the number of columns:

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)

col_combs <- map(0:ncol(test_data), \(i) combn(colnames(test_data), i, simplify = FALSE)) |> unlist(recursive = FALSE) # map and combn create a nested mess, hence the unlist we require here. map_vec doesn't work here for whatever reason
```

Next, for each combination we just created, we run `count()` on it, generating a new dataframe of counts (using `map_df()`). We then create the Total column (faster than renaming `n` then reordering the dataframe), create the Level column by counting the NAs, replace NAs with "All"s, and finally remove the n column:

```
map_df(col_combs, \(x) test_data |> count(across(all_of(x)))) |>
  mutate(Total = n,
        Level = ncol(test_data) - rowSums(across(-n, is.na)),
        across(-n, ~replace_na(.x, "All"))) |>
        select(-n)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 48 × 5
   city  raceeth age_grp Total Level
   <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <int> <dbl>
 1 All   All     All        10     0
 2 chi   All     All         3     1
 3 dc    All     All         2     1
 4 ny    All     All         5     1
 5 All   asian   All         1     1
 6 All   black   All         2     1
 7 All   hisp    All         2     1
 8 All   oth     All         3     1
 9 All   white   All         2     1
10 All   All     0-17        2     1
# ℹ 38 more rows
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks so much!

Comment: Mark, I had a few questions about the script you provided.

In this code, what does the |> do? Is it the same as a pipe %>% ?
test_data |> select(-p) -> test_data

Also, why did you use that approach instead of this one:
test_data <- test_data %>% 
   select(-p)

Comment: re: `|>`: it's the native pipe, introduced in R 4.1. I used it because it's faster than %>%, but also because it's easier to type on my keyboard :P see: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/the-new-r-pipe/ . You can swap it out for %>% and it'll be the same

Comment: re: `test_data |> select(-p) -> test_data`: I did that because I was writing code on the fly, so I'd written the `test_data |> select(-p)` bit first. I think some style guides recommend against assigning variables this way, but it's all the same really

Comment: Okay, Mark. That makes sense. Thanks again! Saved me so much time!

Answer (score 0):

w/o packages we can use `table` iteratively. First, look what using `table` gives on the first columns.

```
> table(dat[1:2]) |> as.data.frame()
   city raceeth Freq
1   chi   asian    0
2    dc   asian    0
3    ny   asian    1
```

We just have to apply this to all `combn`ations like so (the first row we create from `cbind`ing `nrow` and level to an empty structure of the data.frame):

```
> cbn <- lapply(seq_along(dat), \(i) combn(names(dat), i, simplify=F)) |> unlist(F)  ## create combinations non-recursive
> rbind(cbind(array(, c(1, ncol(dat)), list(NULL, names(dat))), Freq=nrow(dat), level=0),  ## create 1st row for `rbind`
+       lapply(cbn, \(i) table(dat[, i, drop=F])) |> lapply(merge, dat[0, ], all=T) |>  ## loop `table` over cbn, `merge` w/ column structure
+         {\(.) Map(cbind, level=lengths(cbn), .)}() |> do.call(what='rbind'))  ## `cbind` levels and `rbind`
    city raceeth age_grp Freq level
1   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   10     0
2    chi    <NA>    <NA>    3     1
3     dc    <NA>    <NA>    2     1
4     ny    <NA>    <NA>    5     1
5   <NA>   asian    <NA>    1     1
6   <NA>   black    <NA>    2     1
7   <NA>    hisp    <NA>    2     1
8   <NA>     oth    <NA>    3     1
9   <NA>   white    <NA>    2     1
10  <NA>    <NA>    0-17    2     1
11  <NA>    <NA>   18-29    3     1
12  <NA>    <NA>   30-49    3     1
13  <NA>    <NA>   50-64    2     1
14   chi   asian    <NA>    0     2
15   chi   black    <NA>    1     2
16   chi    hisp    <NA>    1     2
17   chi     oth    <NA>    1     2
18   chi   white    <NA>    0     2
19    dc   asian    <NA>    0     2
20    dc   black    <NA>    0     2
21    dc    hisp    <NA>    1     2
22    dc     oth    <NA>    0     2
23    dc   white    <NA>    1     2
24    ny   asian    <NA>    1     2
25    ny   black    <NA>    1     2
26    ny    hisp    <NA>    0     2
27    ny     oth    <NA>    2     2
28    ny   white    <NA>    1     2
29   chi    <NA>    0-17    0     2
30   chi    <NA>   18-29    2     2
31   chi    <NA>   30-49    0     2
32   chi    <NA>   50-64    1     2
33    dc    <NA>    0-17    0     2
34    dc    <NA>   18-29    1     2
35    dc    <NA>   30-49    0     2
36    dc    <NA>   50-64    1     2
37    ny    <NA>    0-17    2     2
38    ny    <NA>   18-29    0     2
39    ny    <NA>   30-49    3     2
40    ny    <NA>   50-64    0     2
41  <NA>   asian    0-17    0     2
42  <NA>   asian   18-29    0     2
43  <NA>   asian   30-49    1     2
44  <NA>   asian   50-64    0     2
45  <NA>   black    0-17    0     2
46  <NA>   black   18-29    1     2
47  <NA>   black   30-49    1     2
48  <NA>   black   50-64    0     2
49  <NA>    hisp    0-17    0     2
50  <NA>    hisp   18-29    1     2
51  <NA>    hisp   30-49    0     2
52  <NA>    hisp   50-64    1     2
53  <NA>     oth    0-17    1     2
54  <NA>     oth   18-29    0     2
55  <NA>     oth   30-49    1     2
56  <NA>     oth   50-64    1     2
57  <NA>   white    0-17    1     2
58  <NA>   white   18-29    1     2
59  <NA>   white   30-49    0     2
60  <NA>   white   50-64    0     2
61   chi   asian    0-17    0     3
62   chi   asian   18-29    0     3
63   chi   asian   30-49    0     3
64   chi   asian   50-64    0     3
65   chi   black    0-17    0     3
66   chi   black   18-29    1     3
67   chi   black   30-49    0     3
68   chi   black   50-64    0     3
69   chi    hisp    0-17    0     3
70   chi    hisp   18-29    1     3
71   chi    hisp   30-49    0     3
72   chi    hisp   50-64    0     3
73   chi     oth    0-17    0     3
74   chi     oth   18-29    0     3
75   chi     oth   30-49    0     3
76   chi     oth   50-64    1     3
77   chi   white    0-17    0     3
78   chi   white   18-29    0     3
79   chi   white   30-49    0     3
80   chi   white   50-64    0     3
81    dc   asian    0-17    0     3
82    dc   asian   18-29    0     3
83    dc   asian   30-49    0     3
84    dc   asian   50-64    0     3
85    dc   black    0-17    0     3
86    dc   black   18-29    0     3
87    dc   black   30-49    0     3
88    dc   black   50-64    0     3
89    dc    hisp    0-17    0     3
90    dc    hisp   18-29    0     3
91    dc    hisp   30-49    0     3
92    dc    hisp   50-64    1     3
93    dc     oth    0-17    0     3
94    dc     oth   18-29    0     3
95    dc     oth   30-49    0     3
96    dc     oth   50-64    0     3
97    dc   white    0-17    0     3
98    dc   white   18-29    1     3
99    dc   white   30-49    0     3
100   dc   white   50-64    0     3
101   ny   asian    0-17    0     3
102   ny   asian   18-29    0     3
103   ny   asian   30-49    1     3
104   ny   asian   50-64    0     3
105   ny   black    0-17    0     3
106   ny   black   18-29    0     3
107   ny   black   30-49    1     3
108   ny   black   50-64    0     3
109   ny    hisp    0-17    0     3
110   ny    hisp   18-29    0     3
111   ny    hisp   30-49    0     3
112   ny    hisp   50-64    0     3
113   ny     oth    0-17    1     3
114   ny     oth   18-29    0     3
115   ny     oth   30-49    1     3
116   ny     oth   50-64    0     3
117   ny   white    0-17    1     3
118   ny   white   18-29    0     3
119   ny   white   30-49    0     3
120   ny   white   50-64    0     3
```

If you think, replacing `NA` with all is really needed you can still pipe it in another

```
|>  {\(.) {.[is.na(.)] <- 'All'; .}}()
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(city = c("dc", "ny", "chi", "ny", "ny", "dc", 
"ny", "ny", "chi", "chi"), raceeth = c("white", "black", "hisp", 
"oth", "white", "hisp", "oth", "asian", "oth", "black"), age_grp = c("18-29", 
"30-49", "18-29", "30-49", "0-17", "50-64", "0-17", "30-49", 
"50-64", "18-29")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

Comment: Thanks for passing this along. It also works well!

Comment: @Mark Right, should be `lengths(cbn)`, fixed. Thanks!